# OAuth security for website with API and only external providers

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, clientcredential

I have a .Net core 3.2 site with a RESTful API on one server, and a client website on another server. Users authenticate to the client app via only external providers such as Facebook, Google, or Microsoft. We also have an Identity Server 4.0 that we will be using, but will act just like another external provider.

The issue is that once the user is authenticated on the client, and their granted roles/claims have been determined, how do we request a particular resource from the API? The client web app knows about the user and knows the user is who they say they are, and the client app knows what they can do. How do we relay that information securely to the API?

I was considering client_credentials between the API and the web site, but it seems that is for situations where there is no user, like services or daemons.

I don't want the API to know or care about the users, just that they are authenticated and what their claims are.

Comment: Just to double-check. There is no .NET Core 3.2 version.

Comment: What the client is? Is it a single-page application?

Comment: No, the client is a normal .Net Core Web App with controllers and views

Comment: Then what is the exact question? If you are able to obtain a token, then send it to the properly-configured API. In `.User` property of the controller, you should be able to find the identity of the user which was extracted from an access token.

Comment: The problem is that while I can authenticate to say, Facebook, on the client, I am not getting a token for the API so the API knows the user.

Answer (score 0):

To implement authentication in a single-page application, you need to use [Authorization Code with PKCE](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce) OAuth2 flow. It lets you not store any secrets in your SPA.

> Please don't use `Implicit` flow as it's [deprecated](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead) because of security reasons.

When you send your token from a client to a properly configured .NET Core API, you should be able to read the `User` property of the controller for the identity information.

If you configure the API properly, a request will reach a controller only in case if an access token is valid.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. How to configure the client and the API so that the API can read the User property correctly

Comment: How many providers do you have?
Do you have any code related to auth configuration in `Startup` class?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was JWT Tokens:
On the client, before it sends the bearer token:

```
 protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
            {
                request.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

  public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {

            var longKey = "FA485BA5-76C3-4FF5-8A33-E3693CA97002";

            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(longKey));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim("sub",  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.GetUserId())
            };

            claims.AddRange(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims);
            
            var token =new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "https://localhost:44389",
                audience: "https://localhost:44366",
                claims: claims.ToArray(),
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                signingCredentials: credentials
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

And on the API server

```
 var longKey = "FA485BA5-76C3-4FF5-8A33-E3693CA97002";

            services.AddAuthentication(x=> {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        //ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        //ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:44366",
                        //ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44366",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(longKey)),
                        //ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };

                    
                });
```

Comment: when you have the only API and only client with only server-side logic, your approach is probably valid. for more complex solutions it's better to use a ready token generator combined with well implemented infrastructure for handling all these clients, APIs and, probably, users. Identityserver is such implementation in .Net.

Comment: Yeah, the main idea of having the Identity Server is to decouple client and server. If your key is compromised, you will have to go and update the server-side code and redeploy. So, either you proxy your requests via some gateway, or integrate external providers and Identity Server, or configure your backend to support the fixed set of external providers. What suits you better?